# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn DisplayMember resets to class name after combo box loses focus when binding programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

This is to answer my own question.

In WPF I created a DataGridComboBoxColumn programmatically and bound it to an ObservableCollection of objects and set the DisplayMemberPath to one of the object properties. When the Combo Box drop down was open, the DisplayMember works as intended and I see the property. But when the combo box loses focus instead of seeing the property value in the Combo Box I see the class name for example "{namespace1.Warehouses}" instead of "Warehouse A"

Problematic code (simplified/modified):

Datagrid Item code

```
public class Item{
    public Item(){}        

    private Warehouse itemWarehouse;
    public Warehouse Item_Warehouse{
        get{ return itemWarehouse; }

        set{ itemWarehouse=value; }
    }

}
```

Warehouse class

```
public class Warehouse{
    private string label;
    public Warehouse (string theLabel){
        label=theLabel;
    }
    public string Label{
        get{ return label; }

        set{ label=value; }
    }
}
```

Within the xaml.cs, using this code will cause the Combobox display to reset to the class name instead of Warehouse.Label like it should after the combobox is closed.

```
DataGridComboBoxColumn dataCBColumn = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();

//below three lines cause the problem. When programmatically setting
//DisplayMemberPath it should not be done this way
dataCBColumn.EditingElementStyle = new Style();
dataCBColumn.EditingElementStyle.TargetType = typeof(ComboBox);
dataCBColumn.EditingElementStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(ComboBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty, "Label"));
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

dataCBColumn.ItemsSource = WareHouses; //where WareHouses is of type ObservableCollection<WareHouse>
dataCBColumn.SelectedItemBinding = new Binding("Item_Warehouse"); //this Warehouse refers to the Datagrid Item 'Warehouse' object.
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the correct code for the xaml.cs
Use dataCBColumn.DisplayMemberPath directly instead of editing using Element Style.

```
DataGridComboBoxColumn dataCBColumn = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
dataCBColumn.DisplayMemberPath = "Label";
dataCBColumn.ItemsSource = WareHouses; //where WareHouses is of type ObservableCollection<WareHouse>
dataCBColumn.SelectedItemBinding = new Binding("Item_Warehouse"); //this Warehouse refers to the Datagrid Item 'Warehouse' object.
```